# Extract data separated by a comma from a single cell

Tags: excel, extract, vlookup, vba

I have a spreadsheet with data relating to meetings . One of the cells has the name of meetings with the amount of participants under brackets as follows.

Staff meeting (65), HR meeting (15), Pension meeting (4)

There can be in between 1 to 9 meetings in a single cell. I am looking for a way to extract each meeting name and number (all information between commas) in separate cells.

Does anyone know how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the column  with the meetings.

Then select `Text to Columns` on the Data tab of the Ribbon.

Choose 'Delimited' and the 'Comma' as the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not very good at recursive programming with cell storage.

The solution can be solved with 6 different formulas copied on a number of lines. In this example:

[image: Example of the solution in Excel]

```
The formulas are:
- in B2: =FIND(",",A$1,B1+1)
- in C2: =MID(A$1,B1+1,B2-B1-1)
- in D2: =FIND("(",C2)
- in E2: =FIND(")",C2)
- in F2: =MID(C2,1,D2-1)
- in G2: =MID(C2,D2+1,E2-D2-1)
```

These cells can be copied to the next lines without adaptation, because the line of A$5 is vertically anchored.

Explanation:

- in column B a search is performed from the previous comma (starting with 0) until the last one (ending with LEN()+1).
- in column C the string between the commas is separated
- in column D the location of the '(' character is found
- in column E the location of the ')' character is found
- in column F the text before the '(' character is selected
- in column G the number between the '(' and ')' character is selected

Comment: That's brilliant. Excel hero's solution is quicker. but I will use some of your formulas in case the data needs to be broken down even further with the number of participants in separate cells. Thank you